# How to create a submenu of post lists with counts

Tags: wordpress

How do I create a page that lists posts categories as a horizontal submenu as shown in the image below. Also on navigating to each submenu, a corresponding menu  is displayed to add a post.

This image is from https://www.forcetalks.com/articles/

[image]

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/84992/173390

Comment: Stack Overflow has a rule against questions where the person who asked the question doesn't show they made any attempt at answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get category list as li with count.

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',//Change if you want for other Taxonomy 
    'hide_empty' => false
));
foreach ($terms as $term){
    if($terms->name == 'Draft'){
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $term->slug, 'category' ).'">'.$term->name.'('.$term->count.')</a></li>';
    }   
}
```